# Ping outputs "destination unreachable" on CentOS guest under Windows host

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, centos

This is my VM setup:

- Host: Windows 7 Ultimate 32bit
- Guest: CentOS 6.3 i386
- Oracle VirtualBox 4.1.22
- Networking: Bridge

I can't ping any IP except the router's IP.

```
ping 4.2.2.4 output:
```

[image]

```
ping router ip: 192.168.1.1
```

[image]

```
netstat output
```

[image]

```
ip rout show output
```

[image]

```
ifconfig output
```

[image]

```
resolv.conf contents
```

[image]

Comment: (0) Don’t be so impatient.  (1) Are there other hosts on your local network (e.g., 192.168.1.42)?  Can you ping them?  (2) I hate to ask the dumb question, but can you connect to remote IP addresses with applications/clients such as `telnet`, `ftp`, or mail?  Have you tried any diagnostics tools, such as `netcat` and/or a sniffer?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SuperUser. Your question is very new yet. Please be patient. Answers don't come immediately. Sometimes you have to wait for the right person to come along. Or maybe you need to read [How to Ask Questions the Smart Way](http://www.catb.org/esr/faqs/smart-questions.html) to ask questions that will receive a good response.

Comment: ICMP may be blocked. Try WWW (http) or other protocols, for starters. Also, is your host OS on the same IP subnet as the guest?

Comment: Do not cross-post please. Your questions are off topic for Stack Overflow, so please check out the FAQ of the sites you ask questions on, and don't duplicate them across the network. Thank you!

Comment: @Scott there is no other host on the network. telnet will output network is unreachable and i have not tried and diagnostics tool yet.

Comment: @allquixotic yes the host is on the same ip subnet as the guest. i forget to say iptables and selinux are both disabled and it's true for the host firewall also so then blocking scenario doesn't apply

Comment: (1) So, are you saying that you cannot connect to *any host* other than the router *by any means*?  How do you know that your router is actually connected to the Internet?  (2) Can you login to the router (either through telnet or the serial port)?  It’s been years since I’ve done that, but can you check connectivity directly from the router (e.g., run `ping`, `ftp`, or `telnet` on the router)?  Are there any diagnostic commands you can run on the router that would help us (e.g., display ***the router’s*** routing table?